# Vector space of differentiable functions generated by linear functions

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider any Lie group $G$ and denote by $\mathfrak{g}^*$ the dual space of the Lie algebra of $G$. And consider the usual manifold structure on $\mathfrak{g}^*$. Then, I've heard somewhere that the vector space of differentiable functions on $\mathfrak{g}^*$ is generated by the linear functions.

In what sense could this be true? How we can prove it?

Comment: Could it be that you actually want to consider some more special class of functions? As it stands, the claim seems strange: take $\mathbb{R}$ as (the dual of) the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{S}^1$, and surely the space of linear functions on $\mathbb{R}$ is much smaller than the space of all smooth functions of one variable. Maybe I am missing something, though...

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon, it is certainly strange. But it's something I heard from a researcher (he was saying that we can prove something about the Lie-Poisson structure on $\mathfrak{g}^*$ using linear functions because they generate the rest of them), so I figured it would be correct in some way...

Comment: The linear functions generate (as an algebra) the space of polynomials on $\mathfrak{g}^*$, which is often how they are used in algebraic geometry settings.

Comment: @Joppy, what do you mean by "as an algebra"?

Comment: I mean that you can take sums and products of the functions (meaning pointwise products of functions on a space).